# how to create insert new nodes in JsonNode?

Tags: json, jackson

I have a new JsonNode that I created

```
JsonNode jNode = new ObjectCodec().createObjectNode();
```

with this node, how do I then add key value pairs within so that I can construct this new node with the new values? What I read in http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/08/entry_460.html mentioned about using

```
jNode.with("newNode").put("key1","value1");
```

But looking at the APIs for Jackson's JsonNode (v1.8) does not show any method as such.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

These methods are in `ObjectNode`: the division is such that most read operations are included in `JsonNode`, but mutations in `ObjectNode` and `ArrayNode`.

Note that you can just change first line to be:

```
ObjectNode jNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
// version ObjectMapper has should return ObjectNode type
```

or

```
ObjectNode jNode = (ObjectNode) objectCodec.createObjectNode();
// ObjectCodec is in core part, must be of type JsonNode so need cast
```

Comment: Thank you for this StaxMan.  A follow up question which I forgot to put in is how do I insert this node then into an existing node?

Comment: Usually you add children by using method of `ObjectNode` or `ArrayNode`; mapper is only used for constructing root nodes. So check out `putObject` or `addObject` method in `ObjectNode`/`ArrayNode`

Answer (score 89):

I've recently found even more interesting way to create any `ValueNode` or `ContainerNode` (Jackson v2.3).

```
ObjectNode node = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this. That's what the singleton instance is there for

Comment: Yep, but for some reason I miss a instance method instead a variable reference