# Create Jackson ObjectNode from Object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to add a new item to an existing `ObjectNode`, given a key and a value. The value is specified as an `Object` in the method sig and *should* be one of the types that ObjectNode.set() accepts (`String`, `Integer`, `Boolean`, etc). But I can't just do `myObjectNode.set(key, value);` because value is just an `Object` and of course I get a *"not applicable for the arguments (String, Object)"* error.

My make-it-work solution is to create a function to check the `instanceof` and cast it to create a `ValueNode`:

```
private static ValueNode getValueNode(Object obj) {
  if (obj instanceof Integer) {
    return mapper.createObjectNode().numberNode((Integer)obj);
  }
  if (obj instanceof Boolean) {
    return mapper.createObjectNode().booleanNode((Boolean)obj);
  }
  //...Etc for all the types I expect
}
```

..and then I can use `myObjectNode.set(key, getValueNode(value));`

**There must be a better way** but I'm having trouble finding it.

I'm guessing that there is a way to use `ObjectMapper` but how isn't clear to me at this point. For example [I can write the value out as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786129/converting-java-objects-to-json-with-jackson) but I need it as something I can set on my ObjectNode and needs to be the correct type (ie everything can't just be converted to a String).

Comment: take a look at this post for how to use `JsonNodeFactory` to create an `ObjectNode`:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503604/how-to-create-insert-new-nodes-in-jsonnode

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [ObjectMapper#convertValue](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-) method to covert object to a JsonNode instance. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonConvert {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final ObjectNode root = mapper.createObjectNode();
        root.set("integer", mapper.convertValue(1, JsonNode.class));
        root.set("string", mapper.convertValue("string", JsonNode.class));
        root.set("bool", mapper.convertValue(true, JsonNode.class));
        root.set("array", mapper.convertValue(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"), JsonNode.class));
        System.out.println(root);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"integer":1,"string":"string","bool":true,"array":["a","b","c"]}
```

Answer (score 12):

Using the `put()` methods is a lot easier:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode root = mapper.createObjectNode();

root.put("name1", 1);
root.put("name2", "someString");

ObjectNode child = root.putObject("child");
child.put("name3", 2);
child.put("name4", "someString");
```

This code creates the following JSON structure:

```
{
    "name1": 1,
    "name2": "someString",
    "child": {
        "name3": 2,
        "name4": "someString"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For people who came here for the answer on the question: "How to create Jackson ObjectNode from Object?".

You can do it this way:

```
ObjectNode objectNode = objectMapper.convertValue(yourObject, ObjectNode.class);
```