# Generate an empty set of Json braces- using java & JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2

How to generate an empty json node using jackson-java. I tried with NullNode.instance, but that returns

```
"totals":null
```

Whereas I want totals to be an empty instance.

```
{
  "totals": {},
  "orderId": "550047004",
  "numberOfItems": 2
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create insert new nodes in JsonNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503604/how-to-create-insert-new-nodes-in-jsonnode)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use [`ObjectNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html). It can be [created](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#createObjectNode--) with [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html):

```java
ObjectNode node = mapper.createObjectNode();
```

Comment: Thanks! Just now I tried , new ObjectNode(JsonNodeFactory.instance), and got your answer too (quick) :) .